# need JOLT spec to transform source JSON format to desired JSON format

Tags: jolt

Input JSON is below
[
{
"correlationId": "12345",
"payloadFormat": "Money",
"payload": {
"DE61": "000001000150084063368",
"location": "south",
"name": "Dallas",
"pop": "2M"
}
},
{
"correlationId": "ed1e3",
"payloadFormat": "Cash",
"payload": {
"DE": "000001000150084063368",
"location": "west",
"name": "LosAngeles",
"pop": "4M"
}
}
]

Need to transform as below output message.

[
{

```
"payload": {
"correlationId": "12345",
"payloadFormat": "Money",
  "DE61SF1": "00",
  "DE61SF2": "100015008",
  "DE61SF3": "4063368",
  "location": "south",
  "name": "Dallas",
  "pop": "2M"
}
```

},
{

```
"payload": {
"correlationId": "ed1e3",
 "payloadFormat": "Cash",
  "DE61SF1": "00",
  "DE61SF2": "100015008",
  "DE61SF3": "4063368",
  "location": "west",
  "name": "LosAngeles",
  "pop": "4M"
}
```

}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        // Shift all the DE nodes to a same named node.
        // Here it is moved as TMPDE
        "payload": {
          "DE|DE61": "&2.payload.TMPDE"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 2, 4)",
          "DE61SF2": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 5, 14)",
          "DE61SF3": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 14, 21)"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "correlationId": "[&1].payload.correlationId",
        "payloadFormat": "[&1].payload.payloadFormat",
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "[&2].payload.DE61SF1",
          "DE61SF2": "[&2].payload.DE61SF2",
          "DE61SF3": "[&2].payload.DE61SF3",
          "location": "[&2].payload.location",
          "pop": "[&2].payload.pop",
          "name": "[&2].payload.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jagadesh for this quick help, you are awesome

Comment: Hi Jagadesh, In above problem, can we remove payload while transforming the json, like without payload key form value start from { like {
"correlationId": "12345",
"payloadFormat": "Money",
  "DE61SF1": "00",
  "DE61SF2": "100015008",
  "DE61SF3": "4063368",
  "location": "south",
  "name": "Dallas",
  "pop": "2M"
}

Comment: Yeah. you can do, just remove the `.payload` from the spec.

Comment: Hi Jagadesh, how  we can get the output if  if in input we have received less data like  "DE": "00000100015008" this and we have already define substring for full string, if we not received the data for that if we defined substring, the value of that element should come null.  like output should come  "DE61SF1": "00",
  "DE61SF2": "100015008",
  "DE61SF3": "null",